# Webmail to PHP File

Tags: php, email

I am trying to forward an email from my host's webmail to a php file I have on the server. There's a number of examples of this but I can't get any to work.

Permissions for all associated folders and the file itself have been set to 0755.
The webmail forwarder is as recommended by my host:
|/HOME/ID/htmlFOLDER/subFOLDER/mail.php

The code in mail.php is as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
    $fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
    $email_content = "";
    while (!feof($fd)) {
        $email_content .= fread($fd, 1024);
    }
fclose($fd);

mail('myHomeEmail','Email from PHP!','"' . $email_content . '"');
?>
```

So the process is:

1. I send email from home email to my webmail
2. The webmail should forward to mail.php
3. The file mail.php should then send email back to my home mail. (I get nothing).

If I open mail.php as a webpage I receive an email but the contents ($email_content) is "".
The problem therefore appears to be in the forwarding from my webmail to mail.php.

In the shebang I've also tried #!/usr/**local**/bin/php -q, with or without -q and went through the process of removing any line-end character.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: don't say "forward". that has a very specific meaning in email. your mail server is simply invoking the php script and passing the email body to the script as input. And have you done any basic debugging, like checking if the script is actually executed, if any data is actually read into the script, and what the return value of the `mail()` call is?

Comment: "webmail forwarder" where is that pipe (which is what it is) command actually placed? i suspect you have in a place thats looking for an email address

Comment: Marc B: Well my host refers to the mechanism as a "Forwarder". But I appreciate your point. Re debugging, I've removed all code from the file except the last line. Still nothing.
I'm far from being an expert on this so I'm not sure what I could do.

Comment: Dagon: There is a link in the email section of my host's C-Panel called Forwarders. This opens up a panel to provide the necessary info.

Comment: ok checked an old domain with cpanel, i have a pipe it uses `|php -q /path/script` your pissing the php part

Comment: Dagon: I've tried your suggestion with no luck. The host automatically adds: "|/HOME/ID" at the beginning. So I get: "/HOME/ID/php -q/htmlFolder/subFolder/mail.php".

Comment: then you need to talk to your host.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem turned out to be the end of line character on the shebang line. I thought I'd fixed that by editing the code on my host's file managing tool. Unfortunately my usual editor, Notepad++, put the error straight back in again.

So, for anyone using Notepad++ be aware that the default EOL is Windows format. 
To change the format to Unix go to:
Edit - EOL Conversion - UNIX/OSX Format.